# Canceling asio::steady_timer in owner object's destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I have some encapsulated logic managed by `asio::steady_timer`. There are no needs to invoke this logic after 'real end of object life'. It means no needs to extend object life to last invoking of timer's completion handler. Can I cancel the timer in object's destructor and no wait when completion handler will be invoked?

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
public:
  explicit Foo(asio::io_context& ioc)
    : m_timer(ioc)
  {}

  ~Foo()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_timer.cancel();
  }

  void update()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

    m_timer.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    m_timer.async_wait(
      [=](const boost::system::error_code& ec)
      {
        if (!ec) {
          update();
        }
      }
    );

    // ...
  }

private:
  mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
  asio::steady_timer m_timer;
};

int main()
{
  asio::io_context ioContext;

  auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(ioContext);

  foo->update();

  std::thread thread(
    [&]
    {
      ioContext.run();
    }
  );

  foo.reset();

  thread.join();

  return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

According to [destructor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/_basic_waitable_timer.html) there is really no need to force invoke `cancel()`. So (in case mentioned above) the question is: do I have to keep the encapsulated `steady_timer` alive until  all the completion handlers are invoked?

Comment: Doesn't the [destructor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/_basic_waitable_timer.html) cancel it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my bad code above. Statement *"It means no needs to extend object life to last invoking of timer's completion handler."* is incorrect. Always should to extend object lifetime until all the completion handlers are invoked.

I added public member function `Foo::cancel` to be able external cancel scheduled operations.

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
public:
  explicit Foo(asio::io_context& ioc)
    : m_timer(ioc)
  {}

  void update()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

    auto self(shared_from_this());

    m_timer.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    m_timer.async_wait(
      [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& ec)
      {
        if (!ec) {
          update();
        }
      }
    );

    // ...
  }

  void cancel()
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_timer.cancel();
  }

private:
  mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
  asio::steady_timer m_timer;
};

int main()
{
  asio::io_context ioContext;

  auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(ioContext);

  foo->update();

  std::thread thread(
    [&]
    {
      ioContext.run();
    }
  );

  foo->cancel();
  foo.reset();

  thread.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with the `deadline_timer` (but I would say it is the same mechanism for the `steady timer`) - yes, you have to keep the timer object alive until all completion handlers are invoked. Cancelling the timer did not help in the case of destruction because there was no guarantee that it would be cancelled before the timer being destructed. Since the completion handler may be invoked while the timer object being destructed, a segfault may happen. I had a situation that it was more often reproducible on Windows than on Linux, so be careful how you test it.